# JSON returntype sending NULL to JSON response for navigational properties (Asp.Net Core 3)

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, serialization

I am returning various values to JSON response like this

```
        return Json(new
        {
            alldish.BasePrice,
            alldish.Allergies,
            alldish.Description,
            alldish.DishName,
            alldish.DishSizes
        });
```

this works fine but when i try to send foreign key object inaddition to these properties through same procedure it gives me error instead of giving values

```
    return Json(new
    {
        alldish.BasePrice,
        alldish.Allergies,
        alldish.Description,
        alldish.DishName,
        alldish.DishSizes,
        alldish.DishExtraTypes
    });
```

Actually I want to send same object to another action as a parameter so it can be opened on Edit Page
what are the other possible ways to achieve the same thing?

Comment: Once I had this problem because I accidentally declared an attribute instead of a property (I forgot to put "{get; set}").

Comment: @heringer its a Navigational Property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@L. Vallet was right on that I had to reference it which i did, i performed eager loading like

Actually here DishSize DishExtraTypes were navigational Properties of Dish and they had their own navigational properties as well so i had to get all of them and returned them to JSON response in the form of list As I wanted it in JSON so syntax was as follows

```
        return Json(new
        {
            alldish.BasePrice,
            alldish.Allergies,
            alldish.Description,
            alldish.DishCategoryId,
            alldish.DishName,
            alldish.DishSizes,
            alldish.SubName,
            alldish.Rating,
            DishSize = alldish.DishSizes.Select(dishsize =>
              new
              {
                  BasePrice = dishsize.BasePrice,
                  Diameter = dishsize.Diameter,
                  Size = dishsize.Size
              }),
            DishExtraTypes = alldish.DishExtraTypes.Select(det => new
            {
                ChooseMultiple = det.ChooseMultiple,
                Status = det.Status,
                TypeName = det.TypeName,
                DishExtras = det.DishExtras.Select(dex =>
                      new
                      {
                          ExtraName = dex.ExtraName,
                          ExtraPrice = dex.ExtraPrice,
                          Allergies = dex.Allergies,
                          IsAvailable = dex.IsAvailable,
                          ToppingPrices = dex.SizeToppingPrices.Select(stp =>
                            new
                            {
                                SizeName = stp.SizeName,
                                Price = stp.Price
                            })
                      })
            }).ToList()
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

`DishExtraTypes` seems to be a collection navigation property. You may need to load the related data of your foreign key properties either eagerly, explicitly or lazily :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

If you choose eager loading:

```cs
using (var context = new DishContext())
{
    var dishes = context.Dishes
        .Include(dish => dish.DishSizes)
        .Include(dish => dish.DishExtraTypes)
            .ThenInclude(dishExtraType => dishExtraType.DishExtras)
                .ThenInclude(dishExtra => dishExtra.SizeToppingPrices)
        .ToList();
}
```

If you choose lazy loading:

```cs
// In DbContext

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    => optionsBuilder
        .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
        .UseSqlServer(myConnectionString);
```

Comment: yes it is a navigation property and  i am getting all sort of data correctly in action but the problem comes when i try to pass that data through JSON to ajax response

Comment: Can you add your Dish and DishExtraType classes to your question? As well as the error you mention?